# How do I change a UITextView's size? (I don't need to resize it based on content)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview

It's really just the title. I have no idea how to do this, probably really simple.

Comment: Do you want to do this in code? Just set the `frame` property like any other view.

Comment: @maddy Yes, I want to do this in code. How would I do so?

Comment: I already told you. Set the text view's `frame` property to the desired size and position.

Comment: @abcd3fg Do you want to change it to another view's size???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just assign frame dimensions to your view, in the `ViewDidLoad` method of your view controller, or in the `init` of your parent view, set like this:

```
CGRect yourFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30);  //format is (pixels from left, pixels from top, pixels wide, pixels high)
yourTextView.frame = yourFrame;
```

If you want to modify one of the values, you can't just make adjustments directly, like this

```
yourTextView.frame.size.width += 20;  //THIS WON'T WORK!!!
```

to do something like that, you would need to do this

```
CGRect newFrame = yourTextView.frame;   //find the current frame

newFrame.size.width += 20;              //make any modifications you want

yourTextView.frame = newFrame;          //point your view's frame var to the newFrame
```